# From apk to unity Project

Tags: apk

because I deleted old user with unity project and I have just apk.

I tried program to redelete but it is overwritten.

Is there way to convert it back?

Answer (score 0):

Not as far as I know. There are ways to decompile an APK (say using apktool) and opening the .assets file format of Unity (using Unity assets explorer), but if you're trying to get the entire project out of the apk, I doubt that it's possible.